# Using existing cljs components in a React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/4el0xi/how_to_use_an_existing_reactjs_component_with/

There is this existing post about using existing ReactJS components in a CLJS/Reagent project. I'm looking to do the opposite. I have a bunch of CLJS components and would like to compile them into a ui library of some sort so that they can be used by React developers. That is, if I have a button CLJS component, I would like to be able to render that Button using < Button /> or mylib.Button(_) etc.. in a React/js app file.

I have read this - https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#target-node-library - extensively but it's not quite working out. I've been using ":target :node-library" and I can get simple functions (that return strings/numbers, for example) to compile and work in my app, etc.. but it doesn't work for entire components. For example, my cljs button component takes in :

```
defn button [props & children]
```

but when I try to pass in these parameters (I call {lib.button({}, {})} in my App.js file), I get errors like "No protocol method IMap.-dissoc defined", because I'm trying to pass JS objects into CLJS-only functions, I believe. Not sure how to resolve this..

I can explain more on this if it would help clarify. It would also be super helpful if anyone had a reference demo project or any resources they could link me to.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a few suggestions:

- You can try to build a new sample project to consume your library with `lein new figwheel myproject` and use JavaScript interop to move one step at a time closer to the native JS way of using your library.
- You can create an interface namespace that can consume JS objects and wrap these into Clojure data structures to sort out the protocol errors you're seeing, eg. functions that take a `props` parameter and pass down `(js->clj props)` to the rest of the code underneath.
- For the authoritative source, check the Reagent docs, especially this: http://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/InteropWithReact.html#creating-react-components-from-reagent-components